# What is the geographic representation of the tangent line not existing at (0,0) of the graph f(x) = |x|?

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

Graphically, why isn't the $X$ axis considered a tangent line to the function $f(x) = |x|$ at point $(0,0)$? Is the graph too sharp? (V shaped) for there to be a tangent line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $x$ axis is in fact one of the tangent lines to the graph of $f$ at the origin. The problem is that the tangent is not uniquely defined and as such is analytically uninteresting. Tangents at points where a function is differentiable have very interesting properties (given in part by their uniqueness) which just do not apply to tangents at points where the function is not differentiable.

Comment: Thank you! So I take it, tangent lines can be seen but just aren't considered. What are these interesting properties? Besides the fact that the tangents at differentiable points tell us the slope of the curve.

Comment: @Taehoon That you can find the slope of the tangent is in and of itself a very interesting and very useful property. It can be used for all kinds of things, like making a formula into an [infinite amount of simpler things added together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) which are equal to that formula and [numerically solving $f(x)=0$ for any differentiable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method), and many other things.

Comment: Another thing, that the tangent line varies continuously (in an interval where it's defined). Basically every analytical property of the derivative of a (piecewise) differentiable function corresponds to a geometrical property of the tangent lines.